# Uncaught TypeError: element.remove is not a function

Tags: javascript

I get the error Uncaught TypeError: element.remove is not a function when I try to remove multiple elements. My code is:

```js
function removeElements(value, selector) {
  if(value === undefined || selector === undefined) {
    return undefined;
  }
  
  if(value !== true) {
    return false;
  }
  
  const element = document.getElementsByTagName(selector)
  element.remove();
}
```

I don't get the error if I replace `document.getElementsByTagName(selector)` with `document.getElementById(selector)`. How do I fix this?
**Update**
I put @wxker's code snippet in a loop to remove all elements. Here is the final working code:

```js
function removeElements(value, selector) {
    if(value === undefined || selector === undefined || value !== true) {
        return undefined;
    }
    
    for (const element of document.getElementsByTagName(selector)) {
      element.remove();
    }
    
    console.log(`All ${selector} elements removed.`);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like `HTMLCollection` of elements while `document.getElementById` returns just one element. This is because there can be multiple elements with the same tag.

```
var myobjArr = document.getElementsByTagName(selector);
myobjArr[0].remove();
```

The above code snippet will work, but you'll have to manage the index of the array to remove the right element.